# Hyperdb in wordpress 4.8.2

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I have setup new wordpress with latest version and want to setup master slave replication.

I Have Hyperdb plugin which is not working on my latest wordpress for e.g my post/ page / custom post listing are gone.

[image]

How to correct that? Or suggest me any other way to setup master slave replication in new wordpress version.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @SebastianBrosch can't ask plugin-related questions over there, it'll get closed.

Comment: Thanks for addressing me @SebastianBrosch. But well till that time it will not close do you have any idea what is the problem in that??